# pl/sql and msql joins, slow performance

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, inner-join

I am trying to make a reverse calendar. That is when supplied with normal date, it could distinguish what date from the end of the month it is for example.

t_calendar is just a temporary calendar I use, that has the dates, but I want to update it and set inverse_day and inverse_week_of_month columns to the inversed dates.

I succeded to do so on MSQL with the following:

```
   UPDATE @t_calendar
   SET inverse_day = b.max_day_of_month - a.day + 1,
       inverse_week_of_month = ( b.max_day_of_month - a.day ) / 7  + 1
   FROM @t_calendar a
   INNER JOIN ( SELECT year, month, MAX( day ) max_day_of_month FROM @t_calendar GROUP BY year, month ) b  ON b.year = a.year AND b.month = a.month;
```

And I did similar in pl/sql with the following that works:

```
    UPDATE t_calendar a 
   SET inverse_day = customDate1.max_day - a.day + 1,
   inverse_week_of_month = TRUNC(( customDate1.max_day - a.day ) / 7)  + 1
   WHERE customDate1.year = a.year AND customDate1.month = a.month;
```

But it is VERY slow, that is if MSQL takes 2 second, pl/sql will take few minutes. So this is not a good solution I suppose. I tried duplicate the MSQL code on pl/sql, which doesn't seem to work in the same manner as before, as my unit tests are failing:

```
   UPDATE t_calendar
   SET (inverse_day, inverse_week_of_month) = (
        SELECT b.max_day_of_month - a.day + 1, TRUNC(( b.max_day_of_month - a.day ) / 7)  + 1
   FROM t_calendar a
   inner JOIN ( SELECT  year, month, MAX( day ) max_day_of_month FROM t_calendar GROUP BY year, month ) b  
   ON  b.year = a.year AND b.month = a.month
   where rownum <= 1);
```

What ways can I optimise this in pl/sql, as I am quite new to it or make the join work as intended.

Comment: PL/SQL = Oracle, not MySQL.

Comment: Yes. I did succeed on MySQL,  now I am trying to do the same on Oracle.  But I fail to do so.

Comment: Well, there's no PL/SQL code in your examples. You're having a slow SQL query, and to deal with it you need to get an execution plan. Most likely, `t_calendar` is quite big and lacks indexes you could use, but that's just a guess.

Comment: second and third snippets are both from my Oracle SQL Developer functions. And they do use Oracle database. The first query as I mentioned is from MSQL and works just fine, I am trying to get the same results on Oracle function as well. MSQL seems to work FAST, but Oracles second snippet is very slow, and third that is copy of MSQL transfered to Oracle, with changed syntax to compile, does not work the same way.

Comment: Are you sure it's that snippet that is slow, and not something else in the function it's used in? You may be doing many more updates than you think inside a loop, perhaps. If you are sure, how big is the table, what indexes does it have, and how selective are they? Your second Oracle snippet doesn't seem to be correlated properly, and a merge might be clearer anyway.

Comment: Yes. I did test the time it takes to run that and it is exactly those lines that do so. The table is decent, gets to  around 40'000 elements. It has no indexed tho, I will look into adding them and seeing how the performance changes and if it fully solves the slowness problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second and third snippets do not perform the same logic as your first snippet, I think.  The equivalent to your 1st snippet in Oracle SQL (not PL/SQL, which is Oracle's procedural language) would be:

```
UPDATE t_calendar a
SET (inverse_day, inverse_week_of_month) = 
(  SELECT max(b.day) - a.day + 1, TRUNC(( max(b.day) - a.day ) / 7)  + 1
   FROM   t_calendar b
   WHERE  b.year = a.year
   AND    b.month = a.month
 ) u
```

An index on `t_calendar` like this one would probably help too:

```
CREATE INDEX ON t_calendar ( year, month, day desc )
```

Sorry I am not in front of an Oracle database to check for syntax errors, etc.

Comment: My bad on mix-up. Just wanted to clarify that this does work, but the indexing was that actually solved the problem, as without indexing this still takes minutes. However this implementation is still better as it works the same way, but is way more readable than the previously used one.